# Bootstrap alert won't close after initial appearance

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, smarty3

This is a very difficult problem to explain and demo, basically I am using a mixture of PHP, Smarty, Ajax and Bootstrap.

I have a smarty template with an Ajax form in it (this works), a PHP backend which adds the form details into a database (this also works), on success or failure an alert is shown, this alert is from the Bootstrap CSS, it is written to the page as follows.

```
$('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">' + data.message + '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></div>');
```

The alert does display in the page, and the alert does close! However, for example if I or the user should want to use the form again for example, to say add another record to the database, the alert does show, but this time it never closes! So if I add another 10 records and click the submit button after each one as normal I have 10 alert boxes under the form that never close.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what I could do instead that would work perhaps?

The below code closes the alert, but there is some inconsistency as to when the alert closes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        // snip

        var alertTimer1 = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (typeof alertTimer2 === 'undefined') {
                var alertTimer2 = window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#alert').find('.alert').fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function() {
                        $(this).remove();

                        window.clearInterval(alertTimer1);
                        window.clearTimeout(alertTimer2);
                    });
                }, 5000);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` function only execute once where `setInterval` checks on a regular time interval. For example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGPYXB

The better solution could be when you adding alert message set `setTimeout` function after adding message or use `delay` function like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XPpJGe.

Comment: The better solution seems to work, but not fully.  For example when I first submit the form the alert shows then is removed as I would expect, but then the area where the alert was just shown slides back down and nothing is displayed, then it slides back up again.  It only does this the first time, the second time, the alert is shown and then is removed and no black space appears again.

Comment: yeah, the example is not a final solution. if you need further help please paste your modified code, I will try my best

Comment: @AeroMaxx please have a look updated solution here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGPYXB

Answer (score 0):

1. Initializing alert with `$('.alert').alert()`
2. Close it with `$('.alert').alert('close')` or `$('.alert').alert('dispose')`
3. Add the code lines within `setTimeout()` to delay event like so:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  $('.alert').alert('close')
}, 10000)
```

[Bootstrap 3.3 Documentation - Alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#alerts)

[Bootstrap 4.0 Documentation - Alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#methods)

Comment: Not the answer to my question, my question was about closing the alert after a specific period of time.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the edit at that time. Updated accordingly, pretty sure this answers fully your question.

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap's `alert` class. It will help you close the alert box elegantly.

Comment: Not the answer to my question, I am already using the alert class if you read the question.